# can i use (node-ytdl-core) package on vuejs 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, youtube, yt-dlp

Can I use (node-ytdl-core) package on Veujs 3??..

If not. is there any package like it's working on vuejs I have tried ydlp and some other packages, but it doesn't work maybe it work only on nodejs So I'm looking for package to get direct YouTube links

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use Vue or other framework as long as it's client-side app. You cannot run some kind of code in a browser because of its limitations. This is one of such cases